# Rails, Redmine, Mysql and SQL Server encoding problems

Tags: mysql, sql-server, encoding, redmine, ruby-on-rails

We had redmine working with mysql (and mysql works fine with utf8). Now we needed to migrate the database to SQL Server (latin1 is the default for us). The data acentuation is ok in SQL Server after the migration, but in the browser, data coming from the database is showing ? in the acentuation place. What could be the solution to show characters correctly in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

HTML encode it. Browsers support HTML only, and HTML says all non-english characters are to be specially coded.